Excel Pivot Table Combine Main Row from Multiple Columns
Let's say my main data table looks like the following. Our employees can either be a Project Lead, one of the Team Members, or they don't have to participate in a project.



Project Name
Cost
Project Lead
Team Member 1
Team Member 2
Team Member 3




Project A
1000
Jack
Andrew
Annie
David


Project B
2000
David
Paul
Lily
Jack


Project C
3000
Lily
William
Jack
Annie


Project D
4000
Jack
David
Annie
Lily



I am able to Pivot this table into the following, using the "Project Lead" column as the main Row Label:



Row Labels
Project Count
Sum of Cost




Jack
2
5000


- Project A
1
1000


- Project D
1
4000


David
1
2000


- Project B
1
2000


Lily
1
3000


- Project C
1
3000


...
...
...



I am trying to create a Pivot table, where I can see the project participation of each employee. So, same as the previous table, but this time the employee can exist in either Project Lead column or in one of the Team Member columns, and rest of the data will be aggregated. So the result would be:



Row Labels
Project Count
Sum of Cost




Jack
4
10.000


- Project A
1
1000


- Project B
1
2000


- Project C
1
3000


- Project D
1
4000


David
3
7.000


- Project A
1
1000


- Project B
1
2000


- Project D
1
4000


...
...
...



Is it possible to do so in Pivot Table? Or can I somehow combine the rows before creating the Pivot table?
Thanks in advance.

The easiest way to do this would be to convert the table from the current layout before creating the pivot table. This can be done either using VBA or using Power Query. Below is a Power Query code that could work.
Here is a screenshot of the sample output:

    let
      Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("file_name"), null, true),
      #"Navigation 1" = Source{[Item = "Sheet1 (2)", Kind = "Sheet"]}[Data],
      #"Promoted headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Navigation 1", [PromoteAllScalars = true]),
      #"Changed column type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted headers", {{"Project Name", type text}, {"Cost", Int64.Type}, {"Project Lead", type text}, {"Team Member 1", type text}, {"Team Member 2", type text}, {"Team Member 3", type text}}),
      #"Unpivoted other columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed column type", {"Project Name", "Cost"}, "Role", "User Name"),
      #"Added custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted other columns", "CustomRole", each Text.Trim(Text.Remove([Role],{"0".."9"}))),
      #"Removed columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added custom", {"Role"}),
      #"Inserted conditional column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed columns", "Custom", each if [CustomRole] = "Project Lead" then [Cost] else 0),
      #"Removed columns 1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted conditional column", {"Cost"}),
      #"Renamed columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed columns 1", {{"CustomRole", "Role"}, {"Custom", "Cost"}})
    in
      #"Renamed columns"

